# is there any ways to call hidden phtml files in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

When i click

http://localhost/new_magento/fashion.phtml

But there is no files present in root folder in magento.

I have search block then find code from admin panel

```
<a href="{{store url="fashion.phtml"}}">
```

And also i have find code from root directory in block.xml file

```
<a href="{{store direct_url="fashion.phtml">
```

After all, i can not understand how that file calling in form of  "*.phtml" which is not present.

My question is how to find that file?

Please help me.

Comment: Your question is much too broad and does not pin point one specific problem you have. There are many tutorials and even documentation on how to customise css and javascript in Magento 2. Please start by reading those.

Comment: i know very well how to customize css or javascript which file is present? my question about which do not present.please do not west your time .if you know then give me answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url you mentioned can be a Category, Product or CMS page. If it is a CMS page  you can find the content of the page in Admin Under **Content->Pages** and you can get page by searching url key.

If you want to know the path of the file, you can enable template path hint from admin, it will display the file path in frontend.

To Enable template path hint Go to Admin panel, then Go to **Store->Configuration**. Now from left panel navigation select your store from top store view dropdown.

now under **ADVANCED** select **Developer**. After that Under **Debug** Section set **Enabled Template Path Hints for Admin** to **yes**

Comment: above code for just diversity "<a href="{{store url="fashion.phtml"}}">" so i little confused.thank again